# Automatic line breaking at fixed character limit in listings

Tags: listings, line-breaking

Is there a way to make a linebreak within `listings` based on a character limit?

This would sort of be like what most editors (like vim, emacs) have, where after a certain number of characters, say 80 for instance, we get a newline. I know there's one where it breaks at whitespaces, but unfortunately, I have one line that's several characters long with no whitespace - the text is going off the right margin.

Comment: If you switch to `minted` instead, you can use ite options `breaklines` and `breakanywhere`. (See also the example on page 18 of the [`minted` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted).)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how your long line looks like? As far as I know, `listings` doesn't provide such a feature and it would be hard to implement it. But perhaps adding breakpoints using the `literate` option would work in your case.